# YouTube iframe API "player is undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I am making an application which uses the YouTube API to gather a grid of videos from a search string. When a thumbnail is clicked, player.loadVideoByID should run, opening it in a previously defined iFrame. I'm using the player object instead of iframe directly, as I need the timestamps for future functionality (note-taking).

However, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: player is undefined". Why is that? Function scope?

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YouTube API</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function showNote() {
                document.getElementById('note-container').style.display = "block";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <br>
            <h1>YouTube API Search</h1>
        
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for videos">
                    <input type = "image" src = "search.png" id = "search-button"></button>
                </div>

                <div id="keywordPopup" class="popup" style="display: none;">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="customKeyword" placeholder="Enter custom keyword">
                    <button id="submitKeyword">Submit</button>
                    <button id="cancelKeyword">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            <div class = "addKeyword">
                <button id="addKeywordButton" class="add-button">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="category-buttons">
                <button class="category-button" data-category="Software Quality Assurance">Software Quality Assurance</button>
                <button class="category-button" data-category="Computing">Computing</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "content">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="videos"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div id="loading" style="display: none">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="error" style="display:none">
            <p>An error occurred while fetching videos.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="videoScreen" class="screen">
            <div class="screen-content">
                <span class="close" onclick="closeVideo()">&times;</span>
                <iframe id="videoFrame" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p><a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink">
                <img src="save.png" alt="Download" width="60px" height="60px">
                </a></p>
                <input type = "image" style="width:60px;height:60px;" src = "note.png" onclick = "showNote()" id = "note-opener"></button>
            </div>
            
            <!--<div id="note-container" style = "display:none;">
              <h2>Video Notes</h2>
              <ul id="notes-list"></ul>
              <div style="background-color: #fff">
                <input type="text" id="note-text" placeholder="Add note" />
                <button id="add-note">Add Note</button>
              </div>
              <div style="background-color: #fff">
                <select id="video-selector"></select>
                <button id="load-video">Load Video</button>
              </div>
            </div>*-->
            
        </div>
    

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script src="ytsearch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant JS script (excluding note-taking):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var API_KEY = "AIzaSyAYUJirQE2io-hjqAce9IJCQw9D-F6aFNk";   
    var selectedCategories = [];

    $(".category-button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        var categoryKeyword = $(this).data("category");
        var $searchInput = $("#search");
        
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
           selectedCategories.push(categoryKeyword);
        } else {
            selectedCategories = selectedCategories.filter(item => item !== categoryKeyword);
        }

        var combinedCategories = selectedCategories.join(" ");
        if (combinedCategories !== "") {
            $searchInput.val(combinedCategories);
        } else {
            $searchInput.val("");
        }
    });

    $("#search-button").click(function () {
        var search = $("#search").val();
        var videoDuration = "short";
        videoSearch(API_KEY, search, 12, videoDuration);
    });
    
    
    function videoSearch(key, search, maxResults, videoDuration) {
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('videoFrame', {
            playerVars: {
                'playsinline': 1
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                }
            });
          }
           function onPlayerReady(event){
               event.target.playVideo();
           }
           
        $("#videos").empty();
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + key
        + "&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=" + maxResults + "&q=" + search + "&videoDuration=" + videoDuration, 
        
        function(data){
            //populateVideoSelector(data.items);
            var videosContainer = $("<div class='row'></div>");
            console.log(data);
            data.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
                var videoColumn = $("<div class='col-md-4'></div>");
                var videoContainer = $("<div class='video-container'></div>");
        
                // Create an image or link to represent the video thumbnail and trigger the pop-up
                var thumbnail = $("<img src='" + item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url + "' alt='Video Thumbnail'>");
                thumbnail.on("click", function () {
                        player.loadVideoById(item.id.videoId)
                        //openVideo("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + item.id.videoId + "?enablejsapi=1"); 
                         
                         (function () {
                            var textFile = null,
                              makeTextFile = function (text) {
                                var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

                                // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
                                // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
                                if (textFile !== null) {
                                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
                                }

                                textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

                                return textFile;
                              };
                              
                                var link = document.getElementById("downloadlink");
                                link.href = makeTextFile("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + item.id.videoId)})()
                });
        
                var videoTitle = $("<p class='video-title'></p>");
                videoTitle.text(item.snippet.title);
        
                videoContainer.append(thumbnail);
                videoContainer.append(videoTitle);
                videoColumn.append(videoContainer);
                videosContainer.append(videoColumn);
        
                if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
                    $("#videos").append(videosContainer);
                    videosContainer = $("<div class='row'></div>");
                }
            });
            
            window.videoData = data;

            if (videosContainer.children().length > 0){
                $("#videos").append(videosContainer);
            }
        })
    }

    var videoScreen = document.getElementById("videoScreen");
    var videoFrame = document.getElementById("videoFrame");

    function openVideo(videoUrl) {
        videoFrame.src = videoUrl;
        videoScreen.style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeVideo() {
        videoFrame.src = "";
        videoScreen.style.display = "none";
    }

    var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");
    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeVideo);
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target === videoScreen) {
            closeVideo();
        }
    }

    $("#addKeywordButton").click(function (){
        $("#keywordPopup").css("display", "block");
    });

    $("#cancelKeyword").click(function (){
        $("#keywordPopup").css("display", "none");
    });

    $("#submitKeyword").click(function () {
        var customKeyword = $("#customKeyword").val();
        if (customKeyword.trim() !== "") {
            var newCategoryButton = $("<button class='category-button' data-category='" + customKeyword + "'>" + customKeyword + "</button>");
            newCategoryButton.click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                var $searchInput = $("#search");
                if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                    $searchInput.val(customKeyword);
                } else {
                    $searchInput.val("");
                }
            });

            $(".category-buttons").append(newCategoryButton);
            $("#customKeyword").val("");
            $("#keywordPopup").css("display", "none");
        }
    })
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please check if the code you share is complete. When I copy/paste this code on a snippet - example: https://jsfiddle.net/ - it show a few errors...

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I've added the complete code. Sorry!